# C#, IAsyncResult and the thread pool

Tags: c#, threadpool, iasyncresult

I use the `Action<object>.BeginInvoke()` method, does this use the thread pool or not?

I have the following C# code:

```
    List<FileHash> hashList1 = hashList.Where((x, ind) => ind % 2 == 0).ToList();
    List<FileHash> hashList2 = hashList.Where((x, ind) => ind % 2 == 1).ToList();

    Action<object> oddWork = CalcHash;
    Action<object> evenWork = CalcHash;

    IAsyncResult evenHandle = evenWork.BeginInvoke(hashList1, null, null);
    IAsyncResult oddHandle = oddWork.BeginInvoke(hashList2, null, null);

    evenWork.EndInvoke(evenHandle); 
    oddWork.EndInvoke(oddHandle);
```

Is the thread pool used behind the scenes or not? Or does the system create normal threads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this work will occur in the thread pool.  This page in MSDN goes into depth on how BeginInvoke works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx