# What's the difference between using the thread pool and a normal thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I Was reading random questions and answers here on SO and came across this question:

[C#, IAsyncResult and the thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442991/c-iasyncresult-and-the-thread-pool)

The question is asked is X method using the thread pool or using normal threads.

What's the difference between using the thread pool and a normal thread?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The threadpool is typically suitable for short running tasks. It has the limitation that it is a application-wide limited resource (25 per CPU), and there are a lot of internal classes that use the threadpoool, so if you perform a lot of long running tasks you will use up all the threads.

For long running tasks, it's better to use a manually created thread, with its background property set to true.

**Note**: In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` property value is propagated to worker threads queued using the `QueueUserWorkItem` method. In earlier versions, the principal information is not propagated.

**When Not to Use Thread Pool Threads**

There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:

- You require a foreground thread(!).
- You require a thread to have a particular priority.
- You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from starting.
- You need to place threads into a single-threaded apartment. All ThreadPool threads are in the multithreaded apartment.
- You need to have a stable identity associated with the thread, or to dedicate a thread to a task.

**One big difference is that Unhandled exceptions on thread pool threads terminate the process**; with these three exceptions:

- A `ThreadAbortException` is thrown in a thread pool thread, because `Abort` was called.
- An `AppDomainUnloadedException` is thrown in a thread pool thread, because the application domain is being unloaded.
- The common language runtime or a host process terminates the thread.

Some good references are:

[The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)

[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

[Programming the Thread Pool in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx)

**Update**: in response to comments. You can use the `GetAvailableThreads` method to determine the actual number of threads in the thread pool at any given time. `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` is a different quantity. Its the max allowed in the pool before requests are queued, not the actual number of threads currently in the pool.

Comment: According to the documentation the pool maintains 250 worker threads per processor by default.

Comment: Some long running tasks might need the background property to set to false if you want to ensure your thread will finish its work before the app closes (of course this doesn't guarentee it will but at least it won't close under normal circumstances)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: that soundss like a typo. It's 25 per core

Comment: @Mitch: I just checked by calling ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads, it returns 500 (on a dual-core machine).

Comment: The old docs say 25 per core the latest says 250, weird must be a typo

Comment: @Mitch: GetAvailableThreads returns how many threads the ThreadPool has that are currently idle and available for use; the difference betwen GetMaxThreads and GetAvailableThreads will tell you how many worker threads that are currently in use. If you have not any ongoing work in any threadpool thread they should return the same values.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat @Josh its not a type, the number is different depending on the framework version

Comment: @Mitch Wheat ironically what I meant to type was the word typo 
"It's not a typo, the number is different depending on the framework version"

Answer (score 7):

The difference is not between the threads themselves as they will behave the same, the difference is in who manages the lifetime of a thread, and how you use them.

The threadpool in .net is a pool of threads which will grow or shrink, when you queue somethign up for the thread pool to process, it will determine if it needs to start a new thread or will reuse an existing one. You don't have to explicitly create threads.

This is nice but the downside of this there is a limited number of threads available in the threadpool, so if you queue up a long running task this might have a negative impact on your application, since you could be using up a threadpool thread that something else might want to use.

See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) about the thread pool

Answer (score 3):

The ThreadPool holds a number of threads that are ready for you to use, which may eliminate the cost of creating new threads, which is what happens when you create a normal thread.

Answer (score 0):

A threadpool creates threads and assigsn work to a free thread. This way creating and disposing threads for every work item is preventend, since creating and disposing threads is a relativly costly operation.