# Can you use Thread.CurrentPrincipal with F# async workflows?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, authorization

Has anyone used setting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` for authentication within F# asynchronous code?

Was there any pit falls to watch out for, or did it all just work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't sound like a good idea, because `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` relies on the `IPrincipal` associated with a given thread, but inside an async workflow, you may not be running on the same thread all the time.

Consider this example:

```
open System.Threading

let collectThreadInformation jobId =
    async {
        let tId1 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        let tId2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        return jobId, tId1, tId2 }
```

This is a simple async workflow that reports on the thread ID before and after sleeping for a second. Here's what it looks like running 10 of them in parallel:

```
> [1 .. 10]
  |> List.map collectThreadInformation
  |> Async.Parallel
  |> Async.RunSynchronously;;
val it : (int * int * int) [] =
  [|(1, 15, 15); (2, 14, 15); (3, 15, 15); (4, 15, 15); (5, 15, 15);
    (6, 15, 15); (7, 15, 15); (8, 14, 15); (9, 15, 15); (10, 15, 15)|]
```

As you can see, some of the thread IDs have changed from before and after the `Sleep`, e.g. the second tuple: `(2, 14, 15)`. Before the `Sleep` it ran on **thread 14**, but after the sleep, it was resurrected on **thread 15**.

I think it would be safer to pass in an `IPrincipal` instance as a function argument.

Comment: Cool! I had trouble reproducing this at first; changing the sleep to `Async.sleep (100 + ((new System.Random()).Next(1, 10)))` helped.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058523/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-thread-pool-and-a-normal-thread) suggests Thread.CurrentPrincipal is propagated to worker threads. I may need to run some tests to see if that applies to async workflows as well.

Comment: It tends to work that way when you spawn a new thread, but I don't know if it also happens in e.g. async workflows. However, unless it's documented behaviour, I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Several people suggested to me this should work as async runs on the thread pool. After some testing, it appears it does (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had various conflicting responses to this in different places, so I actually built a test program. Running the code below suggests that as `async` workflows run on the ThreadPool, they do actually preserve the thread context.

```
module TestCurrentPrinciple

open System
open System.Security.Principal
open System.Threading

let rand = Random()

let spawnWorkflow userName = 
    async { 
        let identity = GenericIdentity(userName)
        let principle = GenericPrincipal(identity, [||])
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal <- principle
        for i in 1..10000 do
            let principleName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
            if principleName <> userName then 
                failwithf "Mismatch! Principle name %s does not match username %s (Iteration %d)"
                    principleName userName i
            do! Async.Sleep(rand.Next(10))
    }

let names = 
    [ "mavnn"; "ploeh"; "dsyme"; "biboudis"; "MattDrivenDev"; "fssnip"; "marprz_93"; "skillsmatter"; "thinkb4coding" ]

printfn "Starting"
names
|> List.map spawnWorkflow
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> ignore
printfn "Done"
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Which might be interesting for my current project.

Comment: By default async thread jumps around in the thread pool every so many iterations, I think its set to something like 30 or 50 iterations.

Comment: Its actually 300, I just checked.

Comment: So every 300 binds the thread jumps for the next continuation.

Comment: So given the 10,000 binds (rather unscientific) test above, it sounds like it preserves the thread context as it jumps.

Comment: I think so, SynchronizationContext is contained within the TrampolineHolder which calls Post on it.

Comment: Although only for full blown apps, If FSharp.Core is used from a portable context then FX_NO_SYNC_CONTEXT causes the Post to be omitted.

Comment: Keep on forgetting I can actually go and check the code myself! Interesting quick to know about portable, though.

Comment: I think it will only affect CompactFramework 2.0 and 3.5 anyway.